# Template engine + Front end framework

Tags: php, vue.js, templating

I apologize if this is a duplicate, but I honestly didn't find a similar enough question (or more specifically, answer)

I am working a project right now that involves using Twig template engine AND Vue.js on the front end. I know some larger frameworks offer similar combinations (Laravel uses Blade and includes Vue).

Is this too much? For a smaller project (in PHP with an ORM), is there any clear advantage to having both a templating engine AND a front end framework like Vue?

I hope this question is clear enough.

Thanks

Comment: Quite simply, that is up to you. Small projects can easily become big projects. In order not to lose sight of what I aim for when creating projects, I have created myself a set of guidelines. One of them says "Best practices are context dependent". Do you need a templating framework for this project? Do you need one for any project? Really, the only person who can answer those questions is you as the person developing your project. If you feel that it is beneficial to yourself to do so, then you go right ahead and do it.

Comment: I will be honest, that is much more pragmatic than I am used to from this site. And I see your point, both provide specific functionality, but I worry that I might be able to use one for everything (example - it is possible that Vue could replace my routing and Twig, though I am not that proficient in the framework at this point). I appreciate your input, however.

Comment: Vue, being a front end framework, is not capable of performing back end tasks such as routing. As far as finding one thing that does everything, that is what frameworks such as laravel are for. However, even Laravel is built from individual components that are clearly separated, i.e. the templating library does not route. To have such a module would only cause unnecessary confusion, unforeseen bugs and a steeper learning curve than is necessary.

Comment: There is a Vue router, actually. Works quite well, in fact.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is **very** common, on both small and large apps, and there are benefits and drawbacks as any technology choice would have.

The primary benefit you have is having server-side rendering of your content (at least partially) with the Twig templates, and being able to use server-side code (such as service or model helpers) that output straight to the front-end. If you're not looking to implement a large API on your back-end, having both can be a good choice.

The main drawback here, I believe, is the mental context switch required to change from server to client side, and if you have colliding functionality, you may end up implementing the same feature twice.

In the end, you should consider your experience with both tools, what kind of functionality/experience you're trying to build, and how much time/resources you have available, and make the decision that works best for you :)

Comment: that is as good an answer as any. It is just good to know that I am not walking a obviously bad path.